# UIDatePickerView issue since update to ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uidatepicker

Ive just updated to iOS 8 and I have a problem with my application, everything but the date pickers on the action sheet work. When the action is selected for the action sheet to display along with the date picker added as a subview, the app crashes. I found the problem code which is :

```
-(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet{

theDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
[actionSheet addSubview:theDatePicker];


NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];
[[subviews objectAtIndex:0]setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 46)]; //this line
[[subviews objectAtIndex:1]setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)]; //also this one

}
```

The console log produces this :

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Previously I solved it (badly) by changing each index to 2 & 3 which worked but was a messy implementation.

This is the actual implementation:

```
-(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet{

 theDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
 [actionSheet addSubview:theDatePicker];


 NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];
 [[subviews objectAtIndex:0]setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 46)];
 [[subviews objectAtIndex:1]setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];

}

-(void)datePickerViewFromInput:(NSString*)title{
    SheetPicker=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle: title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"        destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Set", nil];
[SheetPicker showInView:self.view ];
[SheetPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0,117, 325, 383)];
theDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
NSDateFormatter *Formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[Formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

}
```

If i remove the problem code, the action sheet will show, but there is no longer a date picker. (I have no idea why)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably apple change the view hierarchy, [there is a note in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/index.html) that does not really cover your case but still gives us an hint, what is going on:

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

Just as with UIAlerView apple doesn't want us to change it's experience- There-for they do some tinkering with the view hierarchy.

The sanest solution would be to do as suggested by apple: create your one view controller and present it modally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slide change to UIActionSheet in iOS 8. try this code.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[alert.view addSubview:theDatePicker];   
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This works, but to an extent. theDatePicker is not added into the alert controller as a subview, instead its added to the main view. and then it stays there, I would need it to be added into the alert controller so i can also dismiss it.

Comment: you where not far off though, use 

[partentView.view addSubview:TheDatePicker];

Just need to resize the controller view to house the picker.